# Documentation should have a compatibility section

Tags: feature-request, documentation

Something to say which version of browser, languages, etc. support the feature the example refers to.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are talking about something beyond the existing versioning that we have now. That is, it's not a *tag* version but a version of the compiler/interpreter/web-browser that the code can execute on.

I'm not so sure that's a good idea. Users should be able to look at the tag version and look up whether their tools-of-choice support that version/feature.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think we need to replicate caniuse.com or kangax's tables here...

Comment: Now I'm not sure. I didn't see the tag version, and that is half of what I was thinking.
The other half is(as you said) the version of the compiler/interpreter/web-browser that the code can execute on.

I think that if we want a place with the best documentations, would be nice to have all the information there, but maybe we will spend more energy than the gain around this.